# Why axios is not posting data to server for stripe?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

Im followin a youtube tutorial to do payments but I am stucked at a pace that axios could not post data to server

**code**

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Abc from './Abc';
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Abc/>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
  
);
```

**Abc.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import {
  Elements,
  CardElement,
  useStripe,
  useElements
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import axios from "axios";

const CheckoutForm = ({ success }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
    });

    if (!error) {
      const { id } = paymentMethod;

      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post("/api/charge", { id, amount: 1099 });
        console.log(data);
        success();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error is => ',error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      style={{ maxWidth: "400px", margin: "0 auto" }}
    >
      <h2>Price: $10.99 USD</h2>
      <img
        src="https://images.ricardocuisine.com/services/recipes/500x675_7700.jpg"
        style={{ maxWidth: "50px" }}
        alt='abc'
      />
      <CardElement />
      <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
        Pay
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

// you should use env variables here to not commit this
// but it is a public key anyway, so not as sensitive
const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_51JsQsfBbWBJ638dRkTi29yzu85fW6JAvGzbJo9f5RgOtOogcpKnzCfJo6VJoKGemEW54wxrDebWpM8V6vKJl36mC00K3JPAmHr");

const Abc = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState("ready");

  if (status === "success") {
    return <div>Congrats on your empanadas!</div>;
  }

  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <CheckoutForm
        success={() => {
          setStatus("success");
        }}
      />
    </Elements>
  );
};

export default Abc;
```

**charge.js**

```
import Stripe from "stripe";
const stripe = new Stripe("sk_test_51JsQsfBbWBJ638dRR3Iryb907XNtHaeVYhtCRp6SDmaiWmQg51ys2wdB3z6HJ8svutnA8HPMp5yEtdxTSParn3uN00Xb3PJd4o");

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { id, amount } = req.body;

  try {
    const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount,
      currency: "USD",
      description: "Delicious empanadas",
      payment_method: id,
      confirm: true
    });

    console.log(payment);

    return res.status(200).json({
      confirm: "abc123"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: error.message
    });
  }
};
```

but this is giving me error when submitting **xhr.js:210 POST http://localhost:3000/api/charge 404 (Not Found)**

**Hierarchy**

[image: Hierarchy]

any help will be appreciated.I was following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTUYem2IxLA&ab_channel=LeighHalliday tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Next.js set up properly, your `api` folder needs to be in the `/pages` directory.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Comment: How to setup Next.js

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started This should help.  It's pretty easy to get running.

Comment: Can my other pages of project can still remain in **src** folder?

Comment: Which I am not showing here but they are in my other project

Comment: This is how Next.js handles routing: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction.  The src folder can still contain components and other react specific elements like hooks.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without next setup? @MarkWiliams

Comment: You could set up a back end server with something like Express but really Next.js is the easier option by far.

I would take this as an opportunity to learn Next.js.  I honestly think it will become the standard for working with React, particularly with what version 11 of Next is bringing to the table.

Comment: Basically I am working on a React JS project with Django backend so I have already many pages and I don't wanna mess with them to create a new app

Comment: Ah okay I understand.  In that case I think you'll need to use something like https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe and refactor your charge.js code into python.